# function sequence uniform convergence true or false.

Tags: calculus

let $f_n (x) \rightarrow f(x)$ uniform convergence at the Domain $D=(0,1)$, and assume that $f(x)$ continuous and bounded. than Exsit N such that $\forall n>N$ $f_n (x)$ countinous function.

my try: That claim is true. From the assumption $\forall x_0 \in D $ Exsit N such that $|f_n(x_0) - f(x_0)|< \epsilon $ .from that $f(x)$ countionus $f(x_0) = L $ than $|f_n(x_0) - f(x_0)|=|f_n(x_0) - L| < \epsilon$

however, I think that proof incorrect.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f_n : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x)=1/n$ if $x \neq 1/2$, and $f(1/2)=0$. Then obviously $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $0$, but $(f_n)$ is never continuous.

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Counter-example: Let $g:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be defined by $g(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & \mbox{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0, & \mbox{if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}.$ Let $f_{n}:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}g(x)$.
Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=0$. Clearly
$f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly. However, for each $n$, $f_{n}$
is discontinuous everywhere.